# Special character '@' in URL

Tags: http, url

Using the symbol `@` in middle of the URL such as  https://www.google.com@stackoverflow.com redirects to https://stackoverflow.com/ site (domain URL after `@` character).

Why does it redirect to domain mentioned at the end of the URL? Can we stop this type of redirection?

I found that the text before `@` is considered as username and the domain name followed by `@` is considered as email server, so it is automatically redirected.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a redirect, this is part of the URL standard itself, and no this can't be stopped. If you need the `@` character, you'll have to URL-encode it (but this still won't work in the domain name itself, I believe)

From the [URL RFC](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt):

> While the syntax for the rest of the URL may vary depending on the
>      particular scheme selected, URL schemes that involve the direct use
>      of an IP-based protocol to a specified host on the Internet use a
>      common syntax for the scheme-specific data:
>
> ```
> //<user>:<password>@<host>:<port>/<url-path>
> ```
>
> Some or all of the parts ":@", ":",
>      ":", and "/" may be excluded.